# Two API endpoints with same structure but different formats in Open API

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm building an API where I have the following two endpoints `GET /documents/:documentId`
and `GET /documents/types`. I've specified that the format for `documentId` should be a UUID, but when I hit the types endpoint, the system gets confused and redirects to the documentId endpoint. I have the following definitions

DocumentId:

```
components:
  parameters:
     documentId:
       name: documentId
       in: path
       description: The ID of a document to access.
       required: true
       schema:
         type: string
         format: uuid
```

First endpoint (abbreviated):

```
/documents/{documentId}:
  get:
    description: Get a document.
    parameters:
      - $ref: '#/components/parameters/documentId'
    produces:
      - application/json
```

Second endpoint (abbreviated):

```
/documents/types:
  get:
    description: List supported document types.
    tags:
      - Documents
    produces:
      - application/json
    parameters:
      - $ref: '#/components/parameters/active'
      - $ref: '#/components/parameters/limit'
      - $ref: '#/components/parameters/offset'
      - $ref: '#/components/parameters/sort'
```

Is it possible to have both of these, or are they incompatible to have together in the same API set?

Comment: OpenAPI Specification says that templated paths such as `/documents/{documentId}` must be matched first, so it's an issue with your server. What framework/library is your server built with?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you have a mix of OAS2 and OAS3 syntax (`produces` is an OAS2 keyword but `#/components/parameters` is OAS3). Make sure your definition is valid. You can check the syntax in https://editor.swagger.io.

Comment: Thanks @Helen, it turned out to be the order of the endpoints, but I appreciate you pointing out the mixed syntax. Btw, our server is built using NodeJS with express, but we have a custom parser so that we can store the Express code for each endpoint in the same directory with the relevant endpoint.

Comment: The order shouldn't matter. I suggest that you open an issue with the Node.js or express framework that implements routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe its the order you are listing them in. Put the `types` endpoint above the `{documentId}`

Here is an example from the documentation

https://editor.swagger.io/?_ga=2.56132843.1503379663.1608323465-793486363.1608323465

Comment: This worked. I changed the order to put /documents/types first and got the correct response.